# Python AppEngine FQL queries for a few thousand entites

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-fql

I've got a bunch of queries like

```
SELECT total_count from link_stat where url='http://sampleurl.com'
```

I tried to use the FQL multiquery option, but the query length is very large and I get

```
DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I need to keep periodically updating using a cron-job the number of likes that a page has.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try the deferred library and the Task Queue API.